# Why the rule $det(\vec{a}, \vec{b})=-det(\vec{b},\vec{a})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How do these two areas visually cancel out to give a net 0 result?

What's the importance of this rule? Why can't both determinants have the same value?

Comment: There are many good reasons you want your determinant to have a sign.  For one, it makes change of variables in integrals "correct."  The area interpretation is cute, but not the ultimate goal.

Comment: This follows naturally from $$0=\det(a+b,a+b)=\det(a,a)+\det(a,b)+\det(b,a)+\det(b,b)=\det(a,b)+\det(b,a).$$